# Display problem in Endless OS

Tags: linux-kernel, windows, gnome-terminal

I recently installed a Linux based OS called "[Endless OS](https://endlessm.com/)" in my system which is been installed with Windows 10 1607 with Dual Boot features(after installing Endless OS).

My system configuration goes like this :

Processor : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+ 2.10GHz

RAM : 2 GB (1.87 GB Usable)

with 15 inches LED Display.

The problem is that after booting into Endless OS, the splash animation appeared correctly (as of in Ubuntu) and the further display is not clear to be seen.

I even contact in their [community](http://community.endlessm.com/), No reply to this problem.

So, What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: You won't get an answer here as your problem is not clear ("further processed display is not clear to be seen"). Best to keep asking on the Endless OS forums / IRC channels. Be as specific as possible, provide screenshots (or photographs) etc.

Comment: @kba How do I provide screenshots when the display of that EOS is not clear? And I don't have that privilege at present.

Comment: @kba And also suggest me correctly that where do i have to ask this question?

Comment: If you're display freezes or something, you can take photographs of your monitor with a smartphone and use those. I still think it would be "Best to keep asking on the Endless OS forums / IRC channels" with a precise and complete description of your problem.

Comment: @kba Display doesn't freezes and mouse cursor appears as it moves, but the content is not clear. something like black lines or patches

Comment: Cross-posted: http://superuser.com/q/1141600/93541, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/320546/9812.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.